# CSS How to align the box and the description?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm new to ASP.Net CSS. 
Can anyone tell me how can I align my box with its description up(color_box) and down(description).

This is my current issue image.
[My CSS image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbenr.png)

My Html Code Below:

```
<div class="container-box">
<div class="box blue">
    <div class="text blue">Blue</div>
</div>
<div class="box black">
    <div class="text black">Black</div>
</div>
<div class="box green">
    <div class="text green">Green</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My CSS Code Below:

```css
.container-box{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightblue;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 350px;
    padding-left: 80px;

}
.box{
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-left:0.01%;
  border: 80px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  

}

.blue{
    background:blue;
    
}

.black{
    background:black;
}

.green{
    background:green;
}


.text{
    float: left;
    width: 320px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px solid dotted;
    margin:100px;
    margin-right:100%;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container-box">
    <div class="box blue">
        <div class="text blue">Blue</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box black">
        <div class="text black">Black</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box green">
        <div class="text green">Green</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Correct me or please provide me some solution for my doubt. 
Thank you.

Comment: Is this what you try to do ? https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/OjWJpN

Comment: I do it again , ... what is your expected result ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What I want to do is exactly same as your first result code.